# audiorecord android wear values 0

Tags: wear-os, watch, motorola, audiorecord

I am trying to get the volume from my Android Wear watch : MOTO 360.
But, I only get 0 PCM values from Audiorecord.read.....

I run the record process in a separate thread. Below is an extract of my code, do you have any idea what I am doing wrong ?

A big thank for your help

jn.

REREDIT : new result with the MOTO. It looks really really weird!

> 03-15 20:38:08.740    1420-3994/? W/mot_vr_audio_hw﹕ Not allowing wake() since DSP is disabled

RE-EDIT : I tried my code with a different WATCH (Sony). The logs are more explicit

> 03-08 22:11:40.342    1165-1650/? D/MICRO﹕ WILL RECORD AT 44100Hz IN A BUFFER OF 15052
>
> 03-08 22:11:40.343      153-153/? E/AudioPolicyManager﹕ startInput(21) failed: other input 19 already started
>
> 03-08 22:11:40.343    1165-1650/? E/AudioRecord﹕ start() status -38

This error seems to be triggered when 2 audiorecord objects are active at the same time. But I am quite sure mine is only started once. Do you think it could be a System Audiorecord object that prevents mine from being launched?

EDIT : I do have this in my wear manifest
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"

```
private int sampleRateInHz = 8000;
private int channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
private int audioFormat = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;

public void run(){

    running=true;
    bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRateInHz, channelConfig, audioFormat);
    recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,sampleRateInHz, channelConfig, audioFormat, bufferSize);
    Log.d(TAG,"WILL RECORD AT "+sampleRateInHz+"Hz IN A BUFFER OF "+bufferSize);
    recording=true;

    try{
        while (recording){

            if ((recorder.getState()==android.media.AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED)&&(recorder.getRecordingState()==android.media.AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_STOPPED)){
                recorder.startRecording();
                Log.d(TAG,"START RECORDING DUDE");
            }

            int theVolume = getVolume(sampleRateInHz, bufferSize);

            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
        if (!recording){
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            Log.d(TAG,"MIC THREAD STOPPED");
        }

    }catch (InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

private int getVolume(int sampleRate, int bufferSize){
    short[] audioData = new short [bufferSize];

    int nbOfSamples = recorder.read(audioData,0,bufferSize);

    int numSamples = audioData.length;
    int numCrossing = 0;
    double volume = 0;
    for (int p = 0; p < numSamples-1; p++){
        volume += audioData[p]*audioData[p];
    }

    Log.d(TAG,"volume from pcm: "+volume);
    volume = Math.sqrt(volume/nbOfSamples);


    currentVolume = (int) (0.5*currentVolume+ 0.5*volume);
    Log.d(TAG,"currentVolume: "+currentVolume);

    return currentVolume;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

More of your code would be helpful. But it sounds like the mic is already in use. I ran into some of these problems as well. If you are running this in a thread you might accidentally be starting multiple threads. Also if you are running this in a service you might be starting multiple services. Now if you do a Google search, "can multiple instances of the same service be running", you will find a lot of people who say no. But the fact of the matter is yes, you can have multiple instances of the same service running at the same time. My advice is to `Log.d` a random number on each record loop. To make sure only one thread is working at a time

```
public void run(){
    int randThreadNumber = randInt(0,100);
    while (recording) {
        Log.d("MYTAG", "Rand number " + randThreadNumber);
        ..........more code.............
    }
    ..........more code.............
}

public static int randInt(int min, int max) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

    return randomNum;
}
```

Another thing which can cause you to be unable to access the recorder on android Wear is if the watch is listening for "OK Google" So if you try to capture audio while the watch is in a state that will respond to "OK Google" the audio record won't work.

Here is a good way to see if the Mic is available

```
while(recording)
{
    readResult = audio_recorder.read(buf, 0, buf.length);

    //See if read worked
    if(readResult != -3) {
        // yay it worked. Do stuff
    } else {
        // if result is -3 then the watch's mic was inaccessible, wait then retry
        Log.d(TAG, "Waiting for Watch to give up Microphone");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100, 0);
            audio_recorder.startRecording(); // restart audio recording
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "exception", e); // Error trying to sleep thread
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT** Also calling `Thread.sleep(10);` in between each read call is useless as the read method is blocking. If it has nothing to offer it will wait and then return when it is ready.

Comment: thanks for your great reply! I will try your random number tip, it is a very good advice. I will log the readresult=-3 as well, t be able to catch this problem. I wille let yo know the results. An interresting point is that I tried my same code on a different device (sony smartwatch 3) and I have NO PROBLEM accesing the mic'.....

Comment: I didn't get the point about your EDIT. I make the thread sleep AFTER read(). Because I don't need a very high mic sample frequency. I read() is blocking, fine, but I want to pause a minimum time (could be more if read() blocks) before relaunching read() ). Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: I tried your to read the result of audiorecord.read() and it gives me a big positive number like 1323. I think it means that everything seems to be right. But today I have a new ERROR : 03-15 20:38:08.740    1420-3994/? W/mot_vr_audio_hw﹕ Not allowing wake() since DSP is disabled

Comment: @bisonfute If you are still having issues you can message me on google plus https://plus.google.com/+BenjaminNykiel and I can send you an app I  made that uses AudioRecord if you want, just to see if my app works. If it does then I know I can help you. I have not tested my app on Moto 360 though, so my app might not work on your watch. In which case I might not be able to help. Either way this would help us both out, since I would like to know if my app doesn't work on Moto.